# X-UA-Compatible working in developer tools

Tags: html, x-ua-compatible

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

This is a very cool piece of code that forces Chromeframe or latest rendering engine. It can even be sent throught the http headers if you want the html to validate. But with this comes a doubt for me. I use IE8 in compatibility mode to test my websites for IE7 (either clicking the "sheet-of-paper" icon next to the URL box, or by activating "browsing mode" in developer tools). So my question is:

Does compatibility mode still renders webpages as IE7, or does the X-UA instruction blocks my intention?

Im worrying that I think ive checked my pages in IE7 and it turns out what im seeing it's not really what a native IE7 would show....

Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anything you do in developer tools overrides the headers and meta tags.  Here's a [flowchart](http://ieblog.members.winisp.net/misc/How%20IE9%20Determines%20Document%20Mode.png) which explains it all:

[image: IE Compatibility view flochart]

Comment: there seems to be no way of switching off the dev tool settings so they _always_ take precedence..which sucks.

Comment: @nerdess No, that doesn't suck.  If I need to test a web page in IE7 it would suck far more if I had to create a VM to do it because I couldn't override the defaults.  What sucks is intranet sites defaulting to IE7 mode with no way to override from the server.

Answer (score 0):

If IE7 compatibility is really important to you, don't use IE7 mode in IE8/9/10 to test it. Use a virtual machine with a native IE7. IE7 mode in IE8/9/10 doesn't behaves exactly the same as a native IE7. What you worry about is true even if Chrome frame isn't installed.